# 'JSONRenderer' object has no attribute 'has_permission'

Tags: python, django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I am working on react-native and django together in Pycharm. When I run the project. Attribute Error popped up! I don't know how to fix it and there's no related articles on Google for 'JSONRenderer object has no attribute has_permissions'.

[image: Error Screenshot]

Also Internal Server Error is Displaying on terminal.

[image: Internal Server Error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django REST framework: help on object level permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293160/django-rest-framework-help-on-object-level-permission)

Comment: You'll have to include some code where you use `JSONRenderer` because at the moment we can assume that something that is a `JSONRenderer` is then doing `.has_permission` but it's not possible to say any more than that. At the bottom of that traceback will be some very useful information. It's generally helpful to copy the whole traceback from your terminal and paste it into questions.

Answer (score 0):

[Error Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AUkX.jpg)

I wrote these 2 red lines of code in view.py and Error got fixed!